# Google Chrome Extension: How to use an external script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a markdown preview tab for a forum I often use that uses markdown in it's formatting but currently does not have any way to preview what that markdown will look like.

I want to use the [page down](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) markdown converter however I don't know how to use the files inside the content script

here is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Forum Post Previewer",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version":2,
"description":"Adds a preview tab on the post editor",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "*://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": ["previewtab.js"]
    }
],
```

}

and here is the previewtab.js

```html
    // Adding the preview tab
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav nav-tabs");
    var list = document.createElement("li");
    var tab = document.createElement("a");
    tab.innerHTML = "Preview";
    tab.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tab");
    tab.setAttribute("href", "#tab3");
    list.appendChild(tab);
    document.getElementById("post-editor").parentElement.firstElementChild.appendChild(list); 
        
    var content = document.createElement("div");
    content.setAttribute("class", "tab-pane");
    content.setAttribute("id", "tab3");
    var bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.setAttribute("id", "wmd-button-bar");
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.setAttribute("id", "wmd-input");
    textarea.setAttribute("class", "wmd-input");
    var preview = document.createElement("div");
    preview.setAttribute("id", "wmd-preview");
    preview.setAttribute("class", "wmd-panel wmd-preview");
    content.appendChild(bar);
    content.appendChild(textarea);
    content.appendChild(preview);
    document.getElementById("post-editor").appendChild(content);
    
    
    // Using the converter
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
    editor.run();
```

right now I get errors when using the converter because it does not know where `Markdown` has come from.

Can you help me to find out how to use this external script in a chrome extension

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .js files to your extension and include them as content scripts before yours, like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": ["Markdown.Converter", "Markdown.Editor", "Markdown.Sanitizer", "previewtab.js"]
    }
],
```